# Where to see error details in Azure Storage Explorer?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

When I'm running Azure function, it's giving me an error with the following message.

> Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details.
>   Instance ID is 26759a4d-0bec-4a4a-86dc-dbdbf5ce50ed

But I cannot find any output-logs or related information.

> Azure Storage Explorer version: 0.9.4
>
> Azure Functions Cli: 2.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the `Azure function error logs` in three ways.

1.In the **Portal**

Navigate to your function app in the portal, select the `function`, and go to the `Monitor` tab.

2.In the **KUDU**

Access `https://<Your function app name>.scm.azurewebsites.net.` Then you need to select `Tools | WebJobs` dashboard and then choose `Functions`.

3.In the **Table Storage**

All the logging and timing information of your functions output is stored in the Storage Account that was created when you created your Functions App.

More details, please see this [blog](http://markheath.net/post/three-ways-view-error-logs-azure-functions).

Hope it helps you.

---

Update Answer :

The three ways I mentioned above are alternative in Azure side.

For local , I suggest you to get the Dashboard to run locally .You could sync the [dashboard sources code](https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk) and add your Storage `connectionstring` and run the dashboard locally.

Comment: I cannot see anything under function apps, I'm using UseDevelopmentStorage, How will I know my function app name? because I have got this code from somewhere and started working on later. in table storage also, its not showing function and and status

Comment: @viveknuna So, did you create your function app by Azure CLI follow this tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli ?

Comment: @viveknuna Sorry, I don't understand.You said you're running Azure Function in your post, I'm not sure the meaning about without creating function.

Comment: I have created the function like this.
 public static class TestFunctionCls
    {
        [FunctionName("TestFunction")]
        public static async Task TestFunction(

Comment: @viveknuna I see, you ran azure function locally and crashed into the about error. But you cannot find the any log files in your local storage ,right?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. I'm running locally and cannot file any log file

Comment: Thanks I will check and keep you posted

Comment: @viveknuna Sure, waiting for your reply.